# How the connection(s) is/are managed in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm connecting to MongoDB from my Node.js.

If I start my connection from app.js file, then do I need to connect again from another JavaScript file, for example: from one of my models folder?

**Here's my code for database.js:**

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb");

const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

const mongoConnect = callback => {
  MongoClient
    .connect("mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@node.idgpt.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(client => {
      console.log("CONNECTED!!!");
      callback(client);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

module.exports = mongoConnect;
```

**Here's my code of app.js:**

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const errorController = require('./controllers/error');
const mongoConnect = require('./util/database');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminRoutes = require('./routes/admin');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

mongoConnect(() => {
    app.listen(3000);
});
```

So, my question is: Do I need to connect to MongoDB through mongoConnect function every time I want to perform CRUD operation? For example: if I want to insert data from another file which is in models folder, do I need to connect to MongoDB first and then execute the insert operation, because I already first connect to MongoDB from my app.js and then I start listening to my node server.

*Note: I have replaced my username and password with <user> and <password> respectively.*

Answer (score 1):

provide sample code for more insights.

but if you connect in one file you can require this file in many files, it will always be the same connection.

Comment: Well, I'm new to MongoDB and implementing it first time in Node.js. Also, I'm doing it from an online course

Comment: have a nice trip coding bro

Comment: you dont need to connect in every file. because the first launched file is app.js it will always be connected. also if you try to do something using mongo while its not connected already it will wait for the connection to be ready. so everything is good

Comment: Okay, thanks for your answer. I have another doubt: do I need to have an instance of client every time I want to perform operation? Can you also elaborate on how MongoClient.connect() works, what returned object - "client" exactly is, how to access database through that object, cuz I didn't find any useful answers on the Internet. BTW, I have gone through articles and videos on MongoDB theory and am completely aware of collections and documents.